# NIFI delete empty columns with empty values

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a csv file and i need to delete empty columns with empty values.

```
date,A1,A2,A3,A4,A5
2020-07-14 00:00:00.0,,,,10,,
```

Any suggestions please

Comment: why number of columns in header does not correspond to data row? what if you have multiple rows with different empty columns - what should be a result? it's not a standard task - so, why do you need that?

Comment: you can't remove columns and have valid csv afterward, did you meant rows that have empty values for some columns?

Comment: Yes, i mean colomns that have empty values. I'm trying to implement it using a groovy script or jolt (easier maybe) so what do you think ?

Comment: @Akram Did you get anywhere with this? looks exactly like what I'm trying to do now